# Matlab: make a matrix by looping through an index without using a For loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, functional-programming

I have a function `A(k)` which returns a matrix dependent on `k` when I type for example `A(1)`. I want to automatically create the matrix:

```
[A(3)*A(2)*A(1) A(3)*A(2) A(3)]
```

In *Mathematica* I can do for example:

```
Table[Apply[Dot,Table[A(k),{k,3,i,-1}]],{i,1,3}]
```

Assume `A(k)` is a function which returns a 3x3 matrix. For example typing `A(1)` may return:

```
[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
```

**Explanation of Mathematica code**: `Table[A(k),{k,3,i,-1}]` is a "loop" from k=3 to k=i with each iteration decrementing `k` by -1. Therefore the output would be a *list* `{A(3),A(2),...,A(i)}`... obviously k starting from 3 then for i=2 the output list will be `{A(3),A(2)}`. The function `Apply[Dot,Table[A(k),{k,3,i,-1}]]` multiplied the elements of the list together. For i=2 this produces `A(3)*A(2)`. Finally, `Table[Apply[Dot,Table[A(k),{k,3,i,-1}]],{i,1,3}]` applies the same logic as the first statement, looping `i` from 1 to 3. Because the inner table depends on i, this creates a list of elements `{A(3)*A(2)*A(1),A(3)*A(2),A(3)}`. A list is Mathematica's version of a matrix.

How can I achieve the same effect in MATLAB, i.e. not use a for loop to achieve the result? Thanks!

Comment: Am I to assume that the size of your array is 3?  It's not very clear in your example.  I also don't see how the parameter 1 comes into play with regards to the expected output.  Can you provide a couple more examples of what it is you're after?

Comment: The size of `A(k)` is 10x10. But I imagine it shouldn't matter for applicability to different sized arrays.

Comment: `A` is a function with input variable `k` which returns a 10x10 matrix.

Comment: @rayryeng I believe OP wants to have \prod_{k=i}^n next to each other with i\in {1, 2, ..., n}. And `A(k)` is a *function returning a matrix*.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - OK I misread.  I thought it was a matrix.

Comment: Why would you **not** want to use a loop?... especially since you can cache the earlier multiplication and make use of it in the later iterations?

Comment: @rayryeng +1, especially that this seems a bit tough to do without `eval`...

Comment: Because loops take up space and aren't as neat as using dedicated functions - especially knowing that those functions are likely much more optimized. I like functional programming over procedural.

Comment: I mean look at the Mathematica code... with a loop I'd be taking 10 times more space than a single line.

Comment: @space_voyager, using matlab you might want to also consider efficiency. Simple oneliner functions are often much slower and much more inefficient than a proper `for` loop.

Comment: @space_voyager - Not really.  You can use `arrayfun` and that itself is a loop that takes one line of code.  BTW, if `A` returns a matrix, then are you concatenating matrices together in that code?  In addition, depending on what you're coding up, loops can be faster than any built-in vectorized method.  The JIT takes care of that.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes I'm concatenating the matrices.

Comment: My primary problem answering this question is, that I don't understand the mathematica code or the description. It seems you are using `A` as a name for a function and as a name for your data?

Comment: This isn't code golf.  I personally think that a `for` loop is better for your purposes.  Doing it in one-line (to me) will take a couple of `arrayfun/cellfun` calls and a `cell2mat` call to convert everything back.  A `for` loop has more readability and it will definitely be faster.... those are my two cents though.

Comment: Or if you want to stay really smug about it, then define a recursive function to do it. It will be similarly efficient:)

Comment: I edited my question for a better explanation of what I want.

Comment: Just a note: I don't believe Mathematica's lists are matrices. Mma lists are arrays, and embedded lists are matrices. No?

Comment: Yes, Mma matrices are "lists of lists". For example `[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]` would be `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`

Comment: Now having the explanations, I agree with rayryeng. A for loop is probably the most efficient way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, here's a looping version, mostly for subsequent timing checks. This is not the answer you want, but the answer you need;)

```
N = 10; %size of A
old = eye(N);
M2 = [];
for i=3:-1:1
   new = old*A(i);
   M2 = [new M2];
   old = new;
end
```

Or if you want to be *really* efficient (which is probably not the case):

```
N = 10; %size of A
M2 = A(3);
old = M2;
for i=2:-1:1
   new = old*A(i);
   M2 = [new M2];
   old = new;
end
```

Comment: Thank you. It's amazing, over at mathematica.stackexchange people drool over getting everything into functional programming... and here it's the opposite, and both in the name of efficiency. I wonder what is myth and what is fact? I'm a MATLAB guy myself, but recently I came to appreciate Mma's functional syntax.

Comment: @space_voyager It's not the opposite here. In many cases built-in functions are more concise and efficient. You just have to know when to give up. And as for Mma vs matlab: as the saying goes, if you have a hammer it's hard not to see nails everywhere. So the trick is to use those tools which are most suited for the job, and to use them appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215200/2732801) basically is the solution to the problem, but as we are discussing efficient use of matlab I want to leave my thoughts here how to use Matlab efficient. Instead of the large 2D-Matrix it is much simpler to create a 3D-Matrix where the results of each multiplication are stacked. If a 3D-Matrix is acceptable use the code as it is, otherwise comment in the last line to get a 2D-matrix.

```
M3=[];
n=3;
M3(:,:,n) = A(n);
for ix=n-1:-1:1
   M3(:,:,ix) = M3(:,:,ix+1)*A(i);
end
%M3=reshape(M3,size(M3,1),[]);
```

Comment: Did you mean `M3=reshape(M3,10,[]);`?

Comment: I think both 3 or 10 are wrong. Fixed it to work with arbitrary sizes. A good example why not to use magic numbers in code, also removed all other magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayfun()` with indexes as parameters,  eg:

```
%// Compute the product A(3)*A(2)*...*A(idx)
F = @(idx) prod(reshape(cell2mat(arrayfun(A,3:-1:idx, 'UniformOutput', false)),10,10,4-idx),3);
%// Use the last function with idx=1:3
M = cell2mat(arrayfun(F,1:3, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Comment: Are you sure the output dimensions are OK?

Comment: The `arrayfun(A,3:-1:idx, 'UniformOutput', false)` works fine, but `prod(cell2mat(...))` is not returning `A(3)*A(2)*...*A(idx)`

Comment: You are right, I could not try with a real function A returning a matrix. Probably there is a problem with the output of cell2mat, but it's hard to debug without a proper A()

Comment: try `B=rand(10); A=@(x)x*B;`

Comment: Your output seems to differ from `[A(3)*A(2)*A(1) A(3)*A(2) A(3)]`

Comment: It differs because `prod` will do an elementwise product, but you need a matrix product (been there, done that:)